# Extract common names in multiple lists

Tags: r

Good morning everyone,

I have four lists of class "character":

```
list1 <- c("hola1", "hola2", "hola3")
list2 <- c("hola1", "hola2", "hola4")
list3 <- c("hola2", "hola7", "hola8")
list4 <- c("hola1", "hola7", "hola8")
```

I would like to obtain how many items are in common between these lists, like a Venn diagram, so the output:

> Between list1 and list2: hola1 and hola2 are common names.
>       Between list1 and list3: hola2 is a common name.
>       Among list1, list2, and list4: hola1 is a common name.

Or in other words, something like that:

[image]

Something like this. Do you know any package or a method for obtaining this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the holaX's? Are these of type `list`? If so, do you want to compare the names of the variables you assigned them to?

Comment: yes, exactly...........

Comment: You should be careful with the term 'list' in R, because there is a function `list()` to generate objects of class list. What you describe here is a character vector.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `intersect` in combination with `combn`. `intersect` looks for common elements and `combn` will apply it to all 1vs1 combinations of your lists:

```
l <- list(c("hola1", "hola2", "hola3"),
          c("hola1", "hola2", "hola4"),
          c("hola2", "hola7", "hola8"),
          c("hola1", "hola7", "hola8"))

combn(length(l), 2, FUN=function(i)intersect(l[[i[1]]], l[[i[2]]]),
      simplify=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "hola1" "hola2"
#[[2]]
#[1] "hola2"
#[[3]]
#[1] "hola1"
#[[4]]
#[1] "hola2"
#[[5]]
#[1] "hola1"
#[[6]]
#[1] "hola7" "hola8"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `intersect`:

```
> intersect( list1, list2 )
[1] "hola1" "hola2"
```

Answer (score 0):

First put the character vectors in a list. Then extract common names in all lists with Reduce() and intersect().

```
    x <- list(c("hola1", "hola2", "hola3"),
              c("hola1", "hola2", "hola4"),
              c("hola2", "hola7", "hola8"),
              c("hola1", "hola7", "hola8"))

    Reduct(intersect, x)
```